# messages overlap when someone still writing message

Tags: asynchronous, rust, tcp, chat, rust-tokio

i'm making tcp client for my tcp-server and i came to the problem, when one user starts to writing message, and someone else send message its overlaps like this: msgstillnotsended someonelsemessage

example screeenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgdFc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuY1o.png)

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader, BufWriter};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();
    let (_stream, stream_handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();

    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(10);

    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut stdin = std::io::stdin().lock();
        loop {
            let mut line = String::new();
            stdin.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
            tx.blocking_send(line).unwrap();
        }
    });

    let (reader, mut writer) = stream.split();

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);

    let mut line = String::new();
    loop {
        line.clear();
        tokio::select! {
            result = reader.read_line(&mut line) => {
                result.unwrap();
                print!("{line}");
                let file = std::fs::File::open("beep.wav").unwrap();
                let beep1 = stream_handle.play_once(std::io::BufReader::new(file)).unwrap();
                beep1.set_volume(0.2);
            }
            result = rx.recv() => {
                let line_write = result.unwrap();
                writer.write_all(line_write.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
                println!("sended!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what should i do, to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you replace the usage of `stdin` with some static strings or at least provide what you entered? Also please provide what you would expect/like to have as output instead.

Comment: @cafce25 first user enters mymessage without sending it, then second user sends message notmymessage, after that first user see in cli mymessagenotmymessage after sending it sends mymessage

Answer (score 1):

> what should i do, to fix this problem?

Probably switch to raw tty mode so you can control input and output *precisely*.

The issue here is that you're getting the input whenever `return` gets pressed while it gets echoed on the fly, and at the same time the output just gets printed out whenever, so if an incoming message arrives while input is being typed, they're going to mix / scramble.

Raw tty mode lets you handle input by the key and allows disabling input echo, so you can control exactly when anything gets printed and you get all the input as it comes in (it means you need to handle all special keys though).

A ~90% solution (as in it should do most of the trick but can not be perfect) is to use ANSI cursor sequences in order to save the cursor position before output, move to an other location, output, then move the cursor back. Hopefully nobody will be typing right as you're doing that, but in most cases it should work. Though you'll probably still need some additional munging to shuffle the content around when the input gets validated in order to avoid new input now overriding old incoming messages. Raw mode is more complicated upfront but it'll have a lot less edge cases.

Comment: can you write down an example?